# Cannot read property 'features' of undefined when use Ext.ux.touch.grid

Tags: grid, sencha-touch-2, extjs4.1

When i use Ext.ux.touch.grid,an error happened?

"Cannot read property 'features' of undefined "

but it only happen when i use it like this,

```
this.testGrid = Ext.create('Geo.view.Grid');
```

in file application.js,a main controller file

```
config: {
   refs: {
        main: 'mainview',
        worklist: 'worklist',
        testGrid: 'testGrid'
    },
```

this is testGrid view file

```
Ext.define('Geo.view.Grid', {
    extend : 'Ext.ux.touch.grid.List',
    xtype  : 'testGrid',

    requires : [
        'Ext.ux.touch.grid.feature.Feature',
        'Ext.ux.touch.grid.feature.Editable',
        'Ext.ux.touch.grid.feature.Sorter',
        'Ext.field.Number',
        'Geo.store.Grid'
    ],

    config : {
        title    : 'Grid',
        store    : true,
        columns  : [
            {
                header    : 'Text',
                dataIndex : 'text',
                width     : '90%',
                editor    : {
                    xtype  : 'textfield'
                }
            },
            {
                header    : 'Amount',
                dataIndex : 'amount',
                width     : '10%',
                editor    : {
                    xtype  : 'numberfield'
                }
            }
        ],
        features : [
            {
                ftype    : 'Ext.ux.touch.grid.feature.Sorter',
                launchFn : 'initialize'
            },
            {
                ftype    : 'Ext.ux.touch.grid.feature.Editable',
                launchFn : 'initialize'
            }
        ]
    },

    applyStore : function() {
        return new Geo.store.Grid();
    }
});
```

When direct use it in main view file,it's Correct

```
 items: [
     {xtype: 'dashboards'},
     {xtype: 'testGrid'}
 ]
```

Who know the reason? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

do you set your store to autoload: true, (?)